# java heap space error in docker container but docker stats showing only 20% utilitzation of ram

Tags: docker

I am trying to learn why a docker container I run constantly fails when my desktop docker -> preferences -> Resources are set to the default CPU 4, RAM 2GB, Disk Image Size 64Gb the docker container I run fails with the "Java Heap Space Error" message.

However, when I up the RAM only to 4GB it completes successfully.

What is confusing me is when I run a docker stat to gather information on the running docker container it shows that the running container is only using 400+ MB of memory when desktop docker resource is set to 2GB of allocated RAM and around 880 MB of usage when set to 4GB of allocated RAM. I was wondering if anyone could explain how/why the docker container is failing with 2GB of allocated ram when docker stat doesnt show it utilizing half of that memory during runtime

Comment: what are you running in your docker container?

Comment: Its a docker image with an executable java program that I was running. Not something i wrote but I was curious what was happening in the docker side of things that would cause it to run out of memory when it wasnt at half the memory utilization capacity in docker stat